# Apache camel "onException" not returning JSON response

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel, camel-rest

I am using apache camel to expose rest endpoint from my application.
When rest endpoint is successfully executed it is returning expected JSON response like below.

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": 123
}
```

when there is an exception, onException camel clause get executed and in that case its not returning json response, instead it return java object representation like below

```
com.mypackage.Response@27f674d
```

Sample route definition as below.

```
    rest("")
    .consumes("application/json")
    .produces("application/json")    
    .post("/endpoint")
    .bindingMode(RestBindingMode.json)
    .type(Request.class)
    .outType(Response.class)
    .to("direct:endpoint")
```

Route endpoint defination

```
onException(Exception.class)
.process(new ExceptionProcessor())
.convertBodyTo(Response.class)
.handled(true);

from("direct:endpoint")
.streamCaching()
.process(...)
.process(...)
.end()
```

ExceptionProcessor sample implementation.

```
public class ExceptionProcessor implements Processor{
    public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception{
        Response res = new Response();
        res.setKey1("value1");
        res.setKey2(123);
        exchange.getMessage().setBody(res);
    }
}
```

Why onException is returning response as java object string representation?
How can it return JSON response in case of exception?

Comment: You should maybe add (in ExceptionProcessor ) a "Content-Type" header with "application/json"